# how to add two fragments in one activity

Tags: android, fragment

Android: I have a list Fragment on an activity.based on the choice, another fragment will be shown on the same activity
but the other fragment should be replaced and i don't know how to do that when the list fragment is fixed !

Comment: you can use FrameLayout and in your code set you first fragment then if need replace fragment by other fragment, using Fragment manager

Comment: Yes using `<FrameLayout>` instead of `<fragment>` is better way when want to replace fragment

Comment: you mean two fragment on a activity at one time or just one?

Comment: Yes, I solved The problem by Using <FrameLayout>.
Thank You all

Answer (score 1):

From google guide for replacing fragments : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

```
// Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it should show
ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
newFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a [guide on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) in the developers portal. Take a look at the ["programmatically add"](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding) part (and at the whole guide actually). In short: you need a ViewGroup that is used as a container for the fragments and a [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) that is used to add/replace fragment in this container.

Something like (taken from the guide):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);//fragment_container is the ID of the ViewGroup container in your layout
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

in your activity.

EDIT:

Long story short - don't put a fixed fragment in your activity's layout. Instead place a container, dynamically [add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment)) your first fragment in the container and replace it with another fragment when you need to do so (by using FragmentTransaction's [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))).